# Accessing spark program via APIs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark mlib program up and running that applies nlp on free text. I would need to access this program through rest apis. For eg: I need to apply ml on each rows of an excel sheet (convert each rows and get back results from the above ml program) by calling these APIs. How would I do that? basically trying to have an API wrapper around a spark program instead of going to jupyter notebook and manually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict only via the rest API then your best solutions could be:
-Convert your model to PMML and make a web app to consume it 
-Convert your model to MLeap and use the mleap-serving/mleap-spring-boot to host your machine learning model.

You can also implement spark in a web env, but you should consider the resource-heavy operations what spark needs.

Also you can use any scala IDE to work on your project. I prefer Intelij IDEA, but you can use Eclipse also. (you don't have to, you can simply export to PMML/Mleap from Jupiter)